# Is there a way to get Chocolatey to show the progress of a download?

Tags: windows, cmd, chocolatey

I just started using Chocolatey and I was wondering is there some flag or setting that I can set to get chocolatey to show me the progress of a download rather than just hanging the terminal. Furthermore, when I do a......

`PS C:>cinst something`
`==================================================================================`
`something is 20% complete`

You know, like how other package managers do it.

Comment: This was here until the 0.9.9 series and logged as a known issue to reimplement - I think Gary answered it below. https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Powershell version of Chocolatey, i.e. version <= 0.9.8.33 there was a progress bar indicating the progress of the download.

However, in the current C# version of Chocolatey (at the time of this comment 0.9.9.6) there is no equivalent for this.  There is an issue to track this feature, so I would suggest you subscribe to this issue:

https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues/56

For updates about when this will be available.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with GitHub issues. I don't understand it says the the issue is closed?

Comment: @coderrick ah, I see the confusion. Nope, Issue 56 is very much still open, see the green open icon near the top left. A referenced issue, number 648, is closed, and it has the red closed icon beside it.